# AJAX vs JQuery Tooltip - UpdatePanel

Tags: asp.net, ajax, asp.net-ajax, jquery

I'm trying to implement flowplayer.org's JQuery tooltip 
http://flowplayer.org/tools/demos/tooltip/form.html
into my webapplication (C#.NET).

I have the following script at Master.Page:

```
           function createTooltip() {



            // select all desired input fields and attach tooltips to them
            $("#aspnetForm :input").tooltip({
                // place tooltip on the right edge
                position: ['center', 'right'],
                // a little tweaking of the position
                offset: [-2, 10],

                // use a simple show/hide effect
                effect: 'fade',

                // custom opacity setting
                opacity: 0.7
            });        
}

        //--add tooltips after every postback (including partial AJAX postbacks)

        function pageLoad(sender, args) {
            if (args.get_isPartialLoad()) {
                createTooltip();
            }
        }
```

That will control this input and several other more:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtEscola" runat="server" Text="" class="tooltipHandle" title="Observações adicionais que sejam prudentes introduzir" MaxLength="100" </asp:TextBox>
```

I have a GridView and DetailsView under an UpdatePanel, after the first partialPostBack, the tooltip will only work with the inputs within that UpdatePanel, and after the next partialPostBacks none will work whatsoever.

If I change from:

```
        function pageLoad(sender, args) {
            if (args.get_isPartialLoad()) {
                createTooltip();
            }
        }
```

to:

```
        function pageLoad(sender, args) {
            createTooltip();
    }
```

Only the input's outside the UpdatePanel will work

If I access directly the input by it's id and class, it will work properly, but that would mean typing them all in:

```
$("#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_DetailsView1_txtEscola.tooltipHandle").tooltip({
```

Any thoughts on how to make all of them bind properly ?
thanks in advance

Comment: You cannot compare Tool-tips to AJAX, there to separate entities and are not related in anyway.

Comment: what do you mean ? I'm relating this post to AJAX because of the partialPostBacks with the UpdatePanels

Answer (score 2):

Managed to solve it with a simple workaround, created a second function for the tooltip creation to affect only the input field inside the detailsview/updatepanel:

```
        function createTooltipOutside() {
        $('.tooltipHandleOutside').tooltip({
            position: ['center', 'right'],
            offset: [-2, 10],
            effect: 'fade',
            opacity: 0.7
        });
    }
    function createTooltipInside() {
        //--call this to add tooltips to any element with a class of "tooltipHandleInside"
        $('.tooltipHandleInside').tooltip({
            position: ['center', 'right'],
            offset: [-2, 10],
            effect: 'fade',
            opacity: 0.7
        });

    }

    //--add tooltips after every postback (including partial AJAX postbacks)

    function pageLoad(sender, args) {
        if (args.get_isPartialLoad()) {
            createTooltipInside();
        }
        createTooltipOutside();
    }
```

I still don't understand why it didn't work before...

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your JavaScript is no longer bound when the update panel is refreshed.

You'll need to execute one of the following code snippets when your Update Panel posts back in order to re-bind the JavaScript.

```
ClientScriptManager cs = Page.ClientScript;
cs.RegisterStartupScript(typeof(Page), "ReApplyJavascript", "<script type=text/JavaScript>createTooltip();</script>", false);
```

OR

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, typeof(Page), "ReApplyJavascript", "<script type=text/JavaScript>createTooltip();</script>", false);
```

Comment: @Rui Santos - If everything works well by hard coding the IDs, then maybe your selector is off. Try selecting everything by the class name $('.tooltipHandle').tooltip({...

Comment: Tried that too, only the input fields outside the updatepanel worked.. I'm running out of ideas